# Posting XML through cURL using --data-binary

Tags: curl

I have this really typical problem. I have an XML file that I have to post to a server. I was told by the network engineer of that site to use the cURL function. The function that he provided to me was...

```
curl --data-binary @/opt/somefile.xml http://1.2.3.4/gateway/submit?source=FOO&conversationid=1234567
```

When I run this command I keep getting the error "Bad URL, returning 400 status"

I have been stuck on this problem for quite a while now and I am getting seriously frustrated. I have tried running...

```
curl http://1.2.3.4/gateway/submit?source=FOO&conversationid=1234567
```

and I am getting a response from the machine "Test Message" along with some identification parameters of the host system. What this would probably mean that the URL of the destination is OK and it is being accessed via the cURL command.

Are there any special requirements for sending XML files via `--data-binary`?
Does the XML need to be formatted in a special way?
Is the syntax of the cURL command incorrect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `&` is interpreted by the shell you should use quotes (`'`) around the URL:

```
curl --data-binary @/opt/somefile.xml 'http://1.2.3.4/gateway/submit?source=FOO&conversationid=1234567'
```

Comment: Thank you Anthon, for you answer. I will try this out and let you know if that worked. One thing though, I did run the curl command with just the URL and it gave me a 'Test Message' response from the server. I assume the creators of the server put that response there to let us know that the server did get our message. I used curl h t t p://1.2.3.4:8081/gateway/submit?source=FOO&conversationid=1234567. If '&' was interpreted by the shell then it should have given me the same error right?

Comment: Also, I hope I do not have the specifically tell the curl that I am uploading an XML file. I read somewhere that curl generally auto-recognizes the file/protocol types.

Comment: @SeemantShankar Not necessarily the same error. The URL is cut of at `&`, so essentially your using `curl http://1.2.3.4/gateway/submit?source=FOO` but since you did not provide POST data where the code that processes it expects it that causes the differense. If you use the same line as the initial in your Q, cut of at & then you should get the Bad URL again. And with the second URL from your Q also cut of you should get Test Message again

Comment: Thanks Anthon! I want to upvote your answer but am not able to since I am new and do not have enough reps :(

Comment: @SeemantShankar If this answer solves your issue please take a minute and click the check mark under the vote count to the left, this will [signify to everyone](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) that your issue's been resolved and is the way that thanks are expressed in the site.

Comment: @Anthon: I tried both double as well as single quotes. I even tried using '\&' instead of '&'. The funny thing is that if I change the URL slightly, and make it curl --data-binary @/opt/somefile.xml "1.2.3.4/httpgateway/…; (Changed 'gateway' to 'httpgateway'), I do not get the Bad URL error anymore. I now get a 404 Not Found error, which probably means that the error has something to do with the URL rather than the syntax of the cURL command. Any thoughts on what could be going on? Is the 400 error server generated?

Comment: @Anthon: Someone also suggested I try curl --data-binary @/opt/somefile.xml -d "source=FOO&conversationid=1234567" h t t p ://1.2.3.4/gateway/submit. I will do so on Monday and let you know if that worked. Although I have a feeling this error is due to something else.

Comment: @SeemantShankar that 404 I would consider normal, no program (part) found that handles the url httpgateway. What is running on the server?

Comment: @Anthon: The server is a CAS (Conditional Access Server) installed by Direct to Home (Satellite Provider) Company. This command basically asks the system to pick an asset from a designated clear storage (Mentioned in the XML file) and encrypt it. Before I go all anal on that company, I just want to ensure that I am not at fault here with the way the cURL command is executed. Are there any special services (HTTPD, etc.) that I need to install to run this command?

Comment: Anthon: Your answer was right all along...basically the reason why the command was not working was because there was a type in the URL. Instead of ...conversationid, I needed to enter ...conversationId.

Comment: @SeemantShankar glad it is resolved